# IOS: Error con Google Maps, no carga el mapa pero si los marcadores

Tags: google-maps, swift, swift4

Google Maps no carga el mapa en iphone, pero cuando conecto el iphone al xcode y ejecuto el proyecto, si carga el mapa correctamente.

Este es el código:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.868, longitude: 151.2086, zoom: 14)
let mapViewtest = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = camera.target
marker.snippet = "Hello World"
//marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
marker.map = mapViewtest

view = mapViewtest
```

La consola me muestra esto, pero nose si tendra algo que ver

> CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/33FC89CC-DC52-4212-A361-F54DD2AC3CD9/App_name.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'

Cua do conecto el iphone al xcode i ejecuto la aplicación aparece el mapa correcto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto la app en el iphone sin conectarlo al xcode el mapa no carga:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira este enlace, hay discrepancias en el código, igual te funciona como está ahí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859024/gmsmarker-not-appearing-on-map?rq=1

Comment: Hola, No, no me sirve, pero gracias @track3r

Comment: @AlbertoMier veo que usas los maps de Google y no los de iOS, creo tener una idea del problema, obtuviste la API Key desde la Google Console, pero que usaste para obtenerlo?

Comment: Hola, @Jorgesys No entiendo a que te refieres con que usé para obtenerlo

Comment: Me puedes decir cual es la idea que has tenido del problema? @Jorgesys

Comment: @AlbertoMier me parece que el problema de no mostrar el mapa y el mensaje que agregas puede deberse  a dos cosas distintas. En cuanto a el mapa si usas el SDK debes obtener una API Key valida que al parecer es así puesto que se muestra el mapa.

Answer (score 2):

En este caso **estas usando los mapas de Google y no de iOS**, primeramente debes asegurar [crear una API Key pero agregar una restricción si usas el SDK para iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key#si_usas_el_product_name_estandar):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo anterior parece ser correcto ya que aunque tu mapa no se ve pero el marker se despliega sin problema, te sugiero llamar [**layoutIfNeeded()**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded):

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

> [**layoutIfNeeded()**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded) Utilice este método para forzar la vista
>   para actualizar su diseño de inmediato. Al usar Diseño automático, el
>   motor de diseño actualiza la posición de las vistas según sea
>   necesario para satisfacer los cambios en las restricciones. Usando la
>   vista que recibe el mensaje como la vista raíz, este método establece
>   el subárbol de vista que comienza en la raíz. Si no hay
>   actualizaciones de disposición pendientes, este método se cierra sin
>   modificar el diseño ni llamar a ninguna devolución de llamada
>   relacionada con el diseño.

Esto puede solucionar el problema.

---

Ahora con respecto al mensaje que comentas en realidad no creo que influya en el despliegue del mapa:

> CoreData: annotation: Failed to load optimized model at path
>   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/33FC89CC-DC52-4212-A361-F54DD2AC3CD9/App_name.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'

Probablemente tu proyecto lo creaste con otra versión de `Core Data` al cambiar a una versión de `Xcode` más reciente indica que no puede cargar el archivo que almacena el modelo de datos .mom al mismo tiempo se genera un .omo

Puedes generar una nueva versión del modelo de datos y compilar con la versión de `Xcode` que estas usando.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmModelFormat.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo de la clave de api lo he provado decenas de veces y esto `self.view.layoutIfNeeded() ` también lo he puesto pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

te paso el bloque de un ejemplo que tengo que funciona sin problemas.

```
     private func crearMapa(){
    let barHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
    let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height


    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: CLLocationDegrees(self.coordenadas.latitud)! , longitude: CLLocationDegrees(self.coordenadas.longitud)!, zoom: 15.0)

    //let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:  19.454166, longitude: -99.112110, zoom: 6.0)


    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight + 100, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight), camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    //view = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()

    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(self.coordenadas.latitud)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(self.coordenadas.longitud)!)

    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView

    self.view.addSubview(mapView)
}
```

Proporcionas muy poco código, no se en que función llamas a la creación del mapa, no importa mucho pero podría ser alguna cosa sin sentido el problema.

Ya intentaste esto ?

```
 self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```